# Insert into one column by selecting another column in other table but how fill the second column

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

i have a table which has two columns i'd fill one of the columns by selecting other table column data but how can i fill the next column cause i can't use VALUE. Here's the code

```
INSERT INTO Numbers(number, val) SELECT LaptopID FROM Laptop WHERE Laptop.Pid = 2
```

as you can see the "val" column left empty how can i fill that?

Comment: That depends on what you want to put in it. Do you want a default value, a value stored in the `Laptop` table, no value (`NULL`) at all, or something else?  *(Also, which variant of SQL?  SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?)*

Comment: u can do following.. INSERT INTO Numbers(number, val) SELECT LaptopID, 1 FROM Laptop WHERE Laptop.Pid = 2  
but what u want to insert into second column that would be question.

Comment: i want to fill the next column with value stored in another table too. this is sql server CE

Comment: @shervin- : Which table? How is that table related to the Laptop table *(Is there a PrimaryKey, ForeignKey relationship)*? What field names, etc?

Comment: @Dems if you look at the code below you'll find the answer

Comment: @shervin- : The answers that you commented on do not *(as you described in your first comment)* draw the second value from another table. Instead they use a default or hard-coded value. If that is what you need, that's great, but it *is* different from your description.

Comment: @Dems yes dude you're right. that was a bit different. anyway thanks to all of you

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `NULL` if the column allows it:

```
INSERT INTO Numbers(number, val)
SELECT LaptopID, NULL
FROM Laptop WHERE Laptop.Pid = 2
```

---

Or use the intended (hardcoded) value that you want.

If number:

```
INSERT INTO Numbers(number, val)
SELECT LaptopID, 2
FROM Laptop WHERE Laptop.Pid = 2
```

or if text:

```
INSERT INTO Numbers(number, val)
SELECT LaptopID, 'val'
FROM Laptop WHERE Laptop.Pid = 2
```

Comment: can we give variable here ? `INSERT INTO Numbers(@columns)` ??

Comment: @columns:= 'column_1, column_2'

Comment: you save my life. much appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a corresponding value that needs to go into number; then you can just put zero or NULL:

Somethign like this---

```
INSERT INTO numbers (number, val)
SELECT NULL, laptopid
  FROM laptop
 WHERE laptop.pid = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You would add it as an argument on the SELECT.  For example:

```
INSERT INTO Numbers(number, val)
    SELECT LaptopID, 'val'
    FROM Laptop
    WHERE Laptop.Pid = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you need an INNER JOIN with that other table, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Numbers(number, val) SELECT L.LaptopID, OT.OTHER_COLUMN FROM Laptop L 
INNER JOIN OTHER_TABLE OT ON L.SOME_COLUMN = OT.ANOTHER_SOME_COLUMN 
WHERE Laptop.Pid = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLCE does not support Multiple table Update etc, so i used the following method

```
SELECT Laptop.LaptopID, Table2.val FROM Laptop, Table2 WHERE
Laptop.Pid = 2  or where laptop.pid= table2.pid
```

then bulk insert using http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO answer(userans) VALUES(OptionA) Select username From answer WHERE username= 'Name';
```

I want to add a data in a column with reference to another column in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO Numbers(number, val)
SELECT LaptopID, '"+yourlabel.Text+"'
FROM Laptop WHERE Laptop.Pid = 2